# Emacs word wrap at a specific column number

Tags: emacs

I like to run my editor full-screen. The only thing is, though, that when I do this, the word wrap only kicks in when the line hits the right edge of the screen. I would like it to do so, already when the line hits, say, column number 200.

How do I do that?

I would like it to happen in all modes, e.g., [Org-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Org-mode). I added the line `(global-visual-line-mode t)` to my `.emacs` file, in order for the word wrapping also to work in `org-mode`.

I'm running Emacs 23.

---

I got it working! Here is what I added to my `.emacs` file to make it happen:

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
  '(lambda() (set-fill-column 80)))
```

Comment: No need to install two hooks: you can call `(turn-on-auto-fill)` inside the lambda and thus get rid of the first line.

Comment: @Thomas So that would be `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook '(lambda() (turn-on-auto-fill) (set-fill-column 80)))` then?

Comment: @JohnWickerson You got it.

Answer (score 50):

Type <kbd>M-x auto-fill-mode</kbd> to activate automatic line-wrapping after a certain column. Then set the actual line width through the variable `fill-column` as described by user *choroba* (<kbd>C-x f</kbd>).

Note though that this works a bit differently from what other text editors do. <kbd>M-q</kbd> will re-format the current paragraph.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that for spacemacs users toggling `auto-fill-mode` is mapped to `SPC t F`.

Comment: Note that the original question is not about spacemacs, though.

Answer (score 24):

You can set the line width with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> (`set-fill-column`).

Afterwards, you might need to hit <kbd>M-q</kbd> to reformat the current paragraph (`fill-paragraph`), or select text to be justified and run `fill-region`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it, but nothing seems to happen. I have tried putting it in my `.emacs` file and everything, but I really can't see any difference.

Comment: You might need to hit `M-q` to reformat the current paragraph (fill-paragraph) or select the text to be justified and run (fill-region).

Comment: And you can of course set this variable, I'm using spacemacs and set `   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     (c-c++ :variables
            fill-column 120
            ...
            )`

Answer (score 10):

The suggestion for `turn-on-auto-fill` will work if you want *hard newlines in the files you're editing*.  If not, and you just want word-wrap, consider instead `visual-fill-column-mode`, which just does the normal word-wrap that would happen at the edge of the window, but at the specified `fill-column`.

Comment: Thanks. (note that this is a third party package: https://github.com/joostkremers/visual-fill-column)

Answer (score 5):

See the Emacs manual (<kbd>C-h r</kbd>), node `Filling`.  See in particular the first subnode in the menu, `Auto Fill`.